# Windows, SMB, net use, for loop, token results with spaces

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, smb

I'm trying to add a function to a batch script, but I can't figure out how to wrap the spaces in the results.

```
REM Checks any existing mappings that should be valid.
FOR /F "tokens=2,3" %%a IN ('NET USE ^| FINDSTR "%SERVERNAMES%"') DO (
    REM  Checks if %%a (drive letter) is reachable.
    Echo  Checking if %%a is reachable.
    Echo.
    dir "%%a" > NUL
    if errorlevel 1 (
        REM  %%a is not reachable so unmap.
        Echo  %%a is not reachable, removing: %%a
        Echo.
        net use /delete %%a
    )
    REM  Checks if %%b (UNC Path) is reachable.
    Echo  Checking if %%b is reachable.
    Echo.
    dir "%%b" > NUL
    if errorlevel 1 (
        REM  %%b is not reachable so unmap.
        Echo  %%b is not reachable, removing: %%b
        Echo.
        net use /delete %%b
    )
)
```

Specifically %%a works fine due to the result being mostly drive letters, but when it gets to %%b which is UNC paths, if it has a space it breaks.

so if the net use result is:

```
 T:  \\Server\Share\FolderName
```

Then:

```
%%a = T:
%%b = \\Server\Share\FolderName
```

This works fine, however if there are spaces in the result:

```
 T:  \\Server\Share\Folder Name
```

Then:

```
%%a = T:
%%b = \\Server\Share\Folder
%%c = Name
```

This breaks the rest of my script =/

Any ideas welcome.

Comment: Use quotes: `"%%a"` `"%%b"`

Comment: Change `FOR /F "tokens=2,3"` to `FOR /F "tokens=2,*"` where token `*` means `rest of line`

Comment: probably easier to parse the output of `wmic netuse get localname,remotepath,connectionstate,status  /format:csv` (whatever you need)

Comment: @jwdonahue If I wrap the %%a in quotes like `FOR /F "tokens=2,3" "%%a"` Then I get the response, `"%a" was unexpected at this time.`

@Magoo If I use  `FOR /F "tokens=2,*" %%a` then it also takes on the description so `%%b = \\Server\Share\Folder Name Microsoft Windows Network`

Comment: @Stephan That actually looks a lot easier, I will try that out and post back here if it works, thanks.

Comment: Couldn't quite figure out parsing wmic in a loop, I will need to do more research on that, however I still have the same issue of keeping the results contained either way, even if I output it to a text document and then figure out how to use a loop to bring in the results it will still break due to spaces.

Comment: [there are a lot of questions and answers about that](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+wmic+output+to+variable)